# Pandas filter datetime column by time frequency

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, filter

title may be a bit confusing. What I mean is, let's say I have a df like:

| date (dd/mm/yyyy) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | w |
| 02/01/2000 | x |
| [...] | [...] |
| 31/12/2009 | y |
| 01/01/2010 | z |

And I want to filter it by three different time frequencies: day, month and year. It's already filtered by day, so 'month' would look like:

| date (dd/mm/yyyy) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | w |
| 01/02/2000 | a |
| 01/03/2000 | b |
| 01/04/2000 | c |
| [...] | [...] |

And 'year':

| date (dd/mm/yyyy) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | w |
| 01/01/2001 | e |
| 01/01/2002 | f |
| 01/01/2003 | g |
| [...] | [...] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a better understanding for which you are asking. I had to create my own pandas date column, but the concept is there for you to work with just replace with your own columns

```
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('01-01-2000', '12-31-2004', freq = 'd'), columns = ['Dates'])
start_date = '2001-02-25'
end_date = '2004-03-21'
df_dates.loc[
    (df_dates['Dates'].between(start_date, end_date)) 
    & 
    (df_dates['Dates'].dt.day.eq(25))
]
```

The downside of this is that it is not very flexible because you will need to manually update your code to have the configuration you would need. However, this should give you the results you are expecting AND you can take this and make a function that would make it easier to use (Making a function that will accept a couple inputs and handle the & statements is probably what I would do in this situation)

Comment: I used 1st of the month as an example, let's say the initial date is February 25th, 2001, end date is March 21st, 2004, and I want it monthly, how'd I'd do it?

Comment: I believe the question didn't match your expectations (or at least my understanding) you are wanting to be able to filter by between some dates? So in your feb 25, 2001 and march 21, 2004 you would want to get all the data between those two dates?

Comment: Let's say *monthly* between Feb 25, 2001 and March 21, 2004, I'd want something like:

| date  | value  |
|---|---|
| Feb 25, 2001  |  x |
| Mar 25, 2001  |  y |
|  Apr 25, 2001 |  z |
| [...]  |  [...] |
|  Jan 25, 2004 |  b |
|  Feb 25, 2004 |  c |

Comment: My main question now is, if the exact day, month doesn't match, how to select next closest value? For instance, let's say monthly from July 25th 2010 to April 25th 2011, but there's only a recorded value for January 24th 2011, not on the 25th, how would I do that based on your example?

Comment: I mean I can think of a couple ways that you might come up with this, but it would require more exception handling that would be best built into a function. In this situation you might just want to make sure that in your start end states the length was > 1 and if not then simply report the only date in there